# meaning of 'I heard her do that one day'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Is the sentence

> 1. I heard her do that one day.

equivalent in meaning to the sentence

> 2. I heard that she did that one day.

?

The first sentence sounds somewhat weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent, and I agree that the first sentence sounds a little odd.

I would interpret the first sentence as "on one day in the past, I heard her do that", for example, if your former neighbour briefly tried playing the drums.

The second sentence is a bit better, and appears to mean that a third party told you that she did something. However, it's a bit ambiguous as to whether the "one day" refers to when she did it, or when you heard it.

I think you can probably say:

> I heard she did that

or

> I heard she used to do that

without any loss of meaning, unless there's some specific context I'm missing.